# Qt 6++ Bluetooth Pairing

Tags: qt, bluetooth, pairing, qt6, qtbluetooth

Info: [bluetooth-changes-qt6](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtbluetooth-changes-qt6.html#qbluetoothlocaldevice)

> The pairing agent related API was removed without replacement. This includes pairingConfirmation(bool), pairingDisplayPinCode(..) & pairingDisplayConfirmation(..).

I would like to know:

1. Why it has disappeared
2. Even though it says there is no replacement. If there is any alternative way.

Thanks :)

Comment: Regarding you first question: This might be better suited for a Qt forum where the responsible developers for this change are able to answer you

Comment: Hello Michael, actually its true. Im going to move the post to QtForum. 
Thank you!